# .htaccess password not working for all files

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rackspace

My .htaccess on Rackspace looks like this:

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /path-to-htdocs/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Now I would expect this to password protect the whole directory, however, it only protects files with .php extension! What is wrong with it? Is it something in the default http.conf that I cannot override? The path used to .htpasswd is correct as it accepts the user/passwd in the case of .php

Answer (score 1):

Look in your `httpd.conf` file for any `<Directory>` directives that may be overriding your `.htaccess` instructions.

Also look at the files in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` directory (depending on which Linux distro you may be on), or wherever else you're keeping files that get included automatically.

Directives in `httpd.con` file have highest priority, and any directives you issue in `.htaccess` are only followed if they do not conflict with httpd.conf directives.